# django grandparent parent child relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have Django rest frame work with below model

```
class Grandparent(models.Model):
    grandparent_name = CharField(max_length=20)
    grandparent_address = CharField(max_length=20)
    grandparent_phone = CharField(max_length=20)

class Parent(models.Model):
    grandparent = ForeignKey(Grandparent)
    parent_name = CharField(max_length=20)
    parent_address = CharField(max_length=20)
    parent_phone = CharField(max_length=20)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = ForeignKey(Parent)
    grandparent = ForeignKey(Grandparent)
    child_name = CharField(max_length=20)
```

All 3 models are registered in admin.py. When adding a entry into child model from django admin site, dropdowns for parent and grandparent are independent. In other words, I could select a grandparent and parent, that aren't bound as in "Parent" table.

Here is what I want to achieve:
When a grandparent is selected, parent field should show only a dropdown list that have the selected grandparent per "Parent" model.

How could I achieve this?

Edited: Added address/phone fields to Grandparent and Parent classes.

Comment: I don't quite understand your tree here and why you don't just use a single Model representing a node in a generation tree with parents/children. However, since you want to edit the way the form is showing up in the admin page. You might want to take a look at the official documentation on the Django website about customizing that ([Doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial07/)). I would need more information and perhaps clearer one to help you more with that.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have multiple grandparent entries, each having their own parents and parents in turn having their children. I would appreciate if you could explain "single Model representing a node."

Comment: @FrédéricPerron If you meant a one flat class, I think it may be too much for every entry. Please see edited classes in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built a little model for you if you wish to take a look and see what a single node model would look like.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    # The mother and father are necessary for a children to exist. 
    # Therefore, the children can always be linked with a father and a mother, which 
    # also happens to have a mother and a father, and it goes on and on. (The last children would have blank field)
    # A father or a mother could be ommitted and everything would work just fine.
    mother = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='familymember_mother', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    father = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='familymember_father', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def get_children(self):
        """
        Returns the direct children of this node.
        If there are none, it returns an empty list.
        """
        children_mother_side = list(FamilyMember.objects.filter(mother=self))
        print(children_mother_side)
        children_father_side = list(FamilyMember.objects.filter(father=self))
        return children_mother_side + children_father_side

    def get_grandparents(self):
        """
        Returns the grandparents of this node as a list.
        If there are none, it returns an empty list.
        """
        grand_parents = []
        if self.mother is not None:
            if self.mother.mother is not None:
                grand_parents.append(self.mother.mother)
            if self.mother.father is not None:
                grand_parents.append(self.mother.father)
        if self.father is not None:
            if self.father.mother is not None:
                grand_parents.append(self.father.mother)
            if self.father.father is not None:
                grand_parents.append(self.father.father)
        return grand_parents

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.mother == self or self.father == self or (self.mother == self.father and self.mother is not None):
            raise ValidationError('You can\'t have yourself as a parent!')
        return super(FamilyMember, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This model has a method for collecting the grandparents and the children (the parents are obviously accessible too).

This is just an example of what it could look like.

From here, you can edit the admin page form as you wanted to do in the first place with the help of the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial07/).

This class is not perfect, but it should get you started !

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very new to django, I am going to spend some time and digest your model!

Comment: Your welcome @EBUN, please check the answer as the correct solution so that this question can be closed. Good luck !